# Hide referring url parameters

Tags: php, url, parameters

When I call the script using `/landing.php?source=param` I want the script to do a redirect to a URL on another domain, but I don't want the people on the other domain to see the `source=param` parameter in their analytics or server logs, I don't mind them being able to see the `/landing.php` URL.

Any ideas on a solution?

Comment: @kai was stuck for a solution, I realise that the question wasn't complete. I want the landing.php to only redirect to the other domain if the source was a certain value. Setting a cookie is a good solution. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to redirect to an URL on your server (possibly the same page) that doesnt contain the query string first, and then send the user to your off-site destination. You can pass the needed parameter/url on your server with a $_SESSION or $_POST

`/landing.php?source=param` > `/redirect.php` > `www.offsite.com`

Answer (score 0):

In your landing.php, check for the source variable and then redirect it to landing.php or another page without the GET variable e.g. :

```
if(!empty($_GET['source'])){
    // Save the source into a COOKIE / SESSION
    // Then redirect to another page to strip out the GET variable.
    redirect('landing.php');
}
```

Then either in landing.php or another file, just redirect to the offsite URL. You'll have the source in a COOKIE / SESSION to use if you need to do anything else with it.